# Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'crypto.symbols'

Tags: debian, latex

I'm trying to compile a LaTex script on Debian 10 and would like to include the package "crypto.symbols" via

```
\usetikzlibrary{crypto.symbols}
```

Unfortunately, I always end up with the following error message:

```
Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'crypto.symbols'. I lookels.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees.. \usetikzlibrary{crypto.symbols}
```

Which additional package do I have to install to get this script to run?

Comment: This library seems not to be on ctan, but there seems to be a couple of copies on the internet so you would need to install them manually, e.g. https://gitlab.insa-rennes.fr/bviguier/mri/-/tree/d70304a4fb4f43e30199245bde2f5ad418490809/texmf/tex/latex or https://github.com/gravity-postquantum/gravity-sphincs/blob/master/Supporting_Documentation/latex_source/tikzlibrarycrypto.symbols.code.tex (no idea if any of them is official)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I install such a package on Debian? I couldn't find any installation instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the file `tikzlibrarycrypto.symbols.code.tex`. It does not appear to be in TeXlive or elsewhere in Debian. You can download a copy [from IACR](https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/packages/tikzlibrarycrypto.symbols.code.tex).

You also need anything that `tikzlibrarycrypto.symbols.code.tex` depends on. In addition to what is bundled with tikz, it needs [`pgflibraryarrows.new.code.tex`](https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/packages/pgflibraryarrows.new.code.tex).

Download these files and place them in your personal TeX package directory. By default, that's the `texmf` directory in your home directory. Inside this directory, the files need to be under `…/tex/generic` since they're TeX sources that can be used with any format.

```
mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries
cd ~/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries
wget https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/packages/pgflibraryarrows.new.code.tex https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/packages/tikzlibrarycrypto.symbols.code.tex
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187193/how-to-install-tikz-pgf-libraries for more information about the installation.

Answer (score 1):

The package does not seem to be available on CTAN, but there are some copies floating around the internet, e.g. from

- [this repository](https://gitlab.insa-rennes.fr/bviguier/mri/-/tree/d70304a4fb4f43e30199245bde2f5ad418490809/texmf/tex/latex)
- [this GitHub page](https://github.com/gravity-postquantum/gravity-sphincs/blob/master/Supporting_Documentation/latex_source)

(no idea if any of them is official)

You'll have to manually install them by downloading the files and either place them in your

- working directory, e.g. the folder your `.tex` file is in
- `~/texmf` directory, see [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html) for further instructions